# Asp.Net MVC C# Cannot Implicitly Convert Type Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm just drawing a blank here.

The error I get on the "purchases = purchases.Where" line is:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<WWLTracker.Models.StockPurchase>' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WWLTracker.Models.StockPurchase>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

My domain model/class is:

```
public class StockPurchase
{
    public int StockPurchaseId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Date of purchase")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double Amount { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
    // GET: /Popular/
    public ActionResult Index(DateTime? From, DateTime? To)
    {
        var purchases = db.StockPurchases;

        if (From != null && To != null)
        {
            purchases = purchases.Where(x => x.Date >= From && x.Date <= To);
        }
        Return View(purchases.ToList());
    }
```

I know this is something simple - can anyone please advise what I'm missing?

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: sql type for Date and Amount is?

Comment: try   var purchases = db.StockPurchases.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable().ToList();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `purchases` is inferred from the property `db.StockPurchases` which is DbSet. (so the type of `purchases` will become `DbSet<WWLTracker.Models.StockPurchase>`. You can't just convert that later to `IQueryable<WWLTracker.Models.StockPurchase>`.

You should check the shared type between the two results which is `System.Linq.IQueryable<WWLTracker.Models.StockPurchase>` and set the type of `purchases` to that.

Try this:

```
IQueryable<WWLTracker.Models.StockPurchase> purchases = db.StockPurchases;

...
```

Comment: or db.StockPurchases.AsQueryable());??

Comment: Thank you - that worked.  I'll mark as the answer as soon as SO allows. cheers, and thanks for the other suggestions too.

Comment: I am just asking even I wasn't sure..just excited to know tht is it worth using it or not :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you are assigning DbSet of Purchases to variable purchases

```
var purchases = db.StockPurchases;
```

and then you are trying to assign it the result of where clause which is IQeuryable, So it could not convert IQueryable to DbSet that's why you are getting exception.

Change it this way :

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? From, DateTime? To)
{
    List<StockPurchase> purchases = new List<StockPurchase>();
    if (From != null && To != null)
    {
        purchases = db.StockPurchases.Where(x => x.Date >= From && x.Date <= To).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        purchases = db.StockPurchases.ToList();

    }
    Return View(purchases.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your purchases is of type `DBSet` and later you are trying to assigning it your query *an* `IQueryable<T>`. It appears that you want to return a filtered list if your parameters has a value, otherwise you want to return the complete list. You can do that as:

```
// GET: /Popular/
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? From, DateTime? To)
{
    if (From != null && To != null)
    {
        return View(db.StockPurchases.Where(x => x.Date >= From && x.Date <= To).ToList());
    }
    else
    {
        return return View(db.StockPurchases.ToList());
    }
}
```